# Why ROS Lunar reached EOL before Kinetic

Tags: ros-lunar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Just out of curiousity, why did the ros lunar reached EOL before its earlier version ros kinetic. What is the criteria that decides a distributions EOL. ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341205/why-ros-lunar-reached-eol-before-kinetic/) by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> why did the ros lunar reached EOL before its earlier version ros kinetic.

Because ROS Lunar was a *regular* release, while ROS Kinetic is a *long term support* release (LTS).

Regular releases receive(d) 2 year of support. LTS releases 5 year.

As Kinetic was released in 2016, and Lunar in 2017, this leads to Kinetic becoming EOL in 2021 and Lunar in 2019.

Compare this to Ubuntu's [release cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) (which heavily influenced the one used for ROS) where they are called "Long term support and interim releases".

> What is the criteria that decides a distributions EOL. ??

This is probably best explained by reading [wiki/Distributions/ReleasePolicy](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/ReleasePolicy).

As an answer here: the exact criteria are those we (including you, so *the community*) came up with when all of this was discussed. See again the `wiki/Distributions/ReleasePolicy` page which links to a number of different discussions on ROS Discourse and the `ros-users` mailing list.

For ROS 1, the only remaining release (Noetic) will be an LTS (see [wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#Upcoming_releases)). For ROS 2, a similar page is located at [index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on 2020-01-09**:
Thank you so much for explaining. That helps a lot